# mod_rewrite 404s to another domain, keeping path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

It seems like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-U
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://myotherdomain.com/$ [R=301]
```

But that in fact causes nothing at all to be rewritten. I simply want to catch any 404s on this domain and forward them to another domain (full path & query string included).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting idea ... but implementation is wrong, unfortunately. This one, actually, works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) http://myotherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

1. You had no capture group -- you have `.*` but it is not "captured" `(.*)` so it cannot later be referenced via `$1`.
2. You have no back reference (`$1` in our case) -- only `$` symbol on it's own.

Comment: That is kind of helpful, but still isn't correct; with this code, the HTML page requested loads, but none of the associated content (images, CSS, JS) does; they -all- redirect, even though all of those files are there.

Comment: @Nick You misunderstand how it works, unfortunately. Assuming you requesting `http://example.com/nothere.php`, it gets redirected to `http://myotherdomain.com/nothere.php`. Now ALL css/javascript/images are relative to the page or website root UNLESS you HARDCODED FULL DOMAIN NAME as well. If you have `<img src="/logo.png" />` the image will be requested from CURRENT DOAMIN, which after redirect will be `http://myotherdomain.com/logo.php`. If you would have `<img src="http://example.com/logo.png" />` then image will be requested from original domain.

Comment: @Nick The best way -- if you unsure and think that I'm wrong -- is to provide an online example (a page which I can check myself to see how it was coded). If you have something completely different in mind, then your original question is not formulated well at all -- as my answer IS answering your original question.

Comment: Dig that - wish I could post it publicly but cannot. I understand what you're saying, and it works for pages that don't exist, but it also breaks pages that do. The Apache logs back me up: the access.log shows GET /favicon.ico 301, even though it exists. The only object, in fact, that will return at all is /. Every other thing on the server returns 301, and the access.log backs that up.

Comment: @Nick That's interesting... 1) Are those files symlinked somehow? Try adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l` line as well (to the above 2). 2) Can you edit server config .. or virtual host config? If you can -- please enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and check rewrite log after such redirect. Maybe it is get redirected by some other rule elsewhere?

Comment: Yea I was just digging in to the rewrite.log. The problem is the RewriteConds are matching when they shouldn't. (But then, I imagine that's usually the problem with failed mod_rewrite attempts.) It says applying pattern (.*) to uri 'blahblah' pattern='!-f' => matched, even though that should _not_ match. There's got to be something wrong with the way the documentroot is set, I guess? It's not in a Directory statement so RewriteBase isn't an issue (or even allowed). Also tried hitting by either IP or DNS, no change. Still looking into it.

Comment: @Nick That is even more interesting .. and hard to give any real advices from overhere. But  still... Instead of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` try `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}` (although I do not know for sure if it will make any difference).

Comment: @Nick Also ... try debugging with PHP a bit: redirect `/favicon.ico`, for example, to some php file, and pass `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` as parameter: `RewriteRule ^favicon.ico$ /debug.php?file=%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]` where `debug.php` may contain this code: `<?php phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES); ?>`. Now request that file and check the parameters and then manually verify what that file is.

Comment: There we go. That was the ticket - %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.